# Latexmk with makeglossaries and auxdir and outdir?

Tags: glossaries, latexmk

How can I use `glosseries` with latexmk if I use `outdir` and `auxdir` parameters?
I keep getting the `.gls` not found...

Here is my latexmk build script:

```perl
latexmk -outdir=out -auxdir=out -g -f -bibtex -dvi- -pvc -pdflatex="xelatex -synctex=0 %O %S" -pdf $1
```

If I remove the auxdir and outdir param, everything works fine. Any help appreciated.

EDIT: Stop up-voting the answer unless you checked it yourself and it works! Because it does not work for me.

Comment: If you are using Linux, [makelatex](http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~kuhl/software/makelatex) is a similar program written in Python which handles glossaries properly while keeping aux files in a subdirectory. Let me know if you encounter any problems with it.

Comment: Wow, that looks amazing. Does it have a continuous mode like `latexmk` where it watches for changes in source files?

Comment: Also are there cmd-line options.

Comment: `makelatex -l` will continually loop and rebuild the document whenever the source files change. There are command line options which you can see by running `makelatex --help`

Comment: @ScottKu You should really put that into some kind of easy-to-install repository. latexmk already comes with latex live. And I can't find makelatex in arch-linux repos either. Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 15):

The problem is that the `makeglossaries` script fails when it is called with a filename with a path component, e.g., `makeglossaries out/try`.  This can be worked around by defining the necessary custom dependency as follows

```perl
add_cus_dep('glo', 'gls', 0, 'makeglossaries');
sub makeglossaries {
   my ($base_name, $path) = fileparse( $_[0] );
   pushd $path;
   my $return = system "makeglossaries $base_name";
   popd;
   return $return;
}
```

(Note that `pushd` and `popd` are subroutines defined by `latexmk` that do the same as the corresponding commands in UNIX shells.)

Comment: Here is the output I am getting: `Run number 1 of rule 'cusdep glo gls Main'
------------
For rule 'cusdep glo gls Main', running '&do_cusdep(  )' ...
Latexmk: In trying to apply custom-dependency rule
  to make 'Main.gls' from 'Main.glo'
  the source file has disappeared since the last run
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...`

Comment: And at the end: `Latexmk: Missing input file: 'Main.gls' from line
  'No file Main.gls.'
`  `Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  cusdep glo gls Main: failed to create output file
`

Comment: Hellou... anyone there? Why are people upvoting this answer if it does not work???

Comment: @drozzy: I’ve tested the solution with the current CTAN versions of `latexmk` and the `glossaries` package on Debian and it definitely works. Check your versions of `latexmk` and the `glossaries` package and provide a working minimal example. Otherwise, it’s difficult to help you.

Comment: Thank you!!! I was already looking for a solution for two weeks!

Comment: And now it doesn't anymore... Fails with an 6400 error code. But for one hour I actually had a glossary.